# Como inserto una imagen desde VB.net a Sql?

Tags: sql, vb.net

Como inserto una imagen desde VB.net a Sql?

[image: Los datos que tengo en la base de datos]

Ese es la forma que estoy utilizando para guardar los demas datos

```
cmd2.CommandText = "insert into trabajadores (sueldo, acceso, login, password, 
            estado) values ('" + txtsueldo.Text + "','" + cmbacceso.Text + "','" + txtlogin.Text + "', encryptByPassPhrase('L$admin', 
            '" + txtpassword.Text + "'),'" + cmbestado.Text + "')"
```

Comment: Es mejor que copies y pegues el codigo aqui, en lugar de usar la captura de pantalla

Comment: por favor mira [ask]... a que te refieres, al tipo de dato que necesitas en la base de datos?

Comment: cmd2.CommandText = "insert into trabajadores (sueldo, acceso, login, password, 
                estado) values ('" + txtsueldo.Text + "','" + cmbacceso.Text + "','" + txtlogin.Text + "', encryptByPassPhrase('L$admin', 
                '" + txtpassword.Text + "'),'" + cmbestado.Text + "')"

Comment: gbianchi tengo el campo de imagen declarado como una image

Comment: Lo que quiero saber el codigo para poder guardar una imagen a sql desde VB.net

Comment: en que base de datos? supongo que sera sql server pero no lo aclaraste

Comment: Si es en sql server

Comment: ok. saca las imagenes, aclara la base de datos, pega tu codigo y asi podremos tratar de ayudarte. Aclara tambien el tipo de datos a donde va guardada la imagen.mira el link que te pase mas arriba, y usa el [edit] para agregar toda la informacion ahi.

Comment: Realmente estaba viendo videos pero lo hacen con los metodos set y getter y aparte de eso lo hacian con procedimientos almacenados y lo que quiero saber si de esa manera se puede lograr tambien

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437937/Save-and-Retrieve-Image-from-a-SQL-Server-Database Ese enlace tiene lo que necesitas

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que estás implementando una aplicación Windows Forms, el código siguiente que separo en dos pasos te podría ayudar.

1. Seleccionar la imagen y llamar a la función que realiza el guadado
   en BBDD:

   ```
   Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
       Dim openFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog()
       openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = True
       openFileDialog.AddExtension = True
       openFileDialog.Multiselect = True
       openFileDialog.Filter = "Image files (*.png)|*.jpg"
       Dim fichero As [Byte]() = Nothing

       If openFileDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
           Dim rutaArchivo As String = openFileDialog.FileNames(0)
           Dim fs = File.Open(rutaArchivo, FileMode.Open)
           fichero = New [Byte](fs.Length - 1) {}
           fs.Read(fichero, 0, CInt(fs.Length))
           fs.Close()
       End If

       If fichero IsNot Nothing Then
           Guardar(0.00, "test", "test", "test", "test", fichero)
       End If  
   End Sub
   ```
2. Función donde se realiza el guadado en BBDD:

   ```
       Private connection As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
   Public Function Guardar(ByVal sueldo As Decimal, ByVal acceso As String, ByVal login As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal estado As String, ByVal fichero() As [Byte]) As Boolean
       Dim ok As Boolean = False
       Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Trabajadores (sueldo, acceso, login, password, estado, imagen)"
       sql += " VALUES (@sueldo, @acceso, @Fichero, @login, @password, , @estado,@imagen)"

       Try
           Using conexion As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connection)
               Using comando As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, conexion)
                   comando.Parameters.Add("@sueldo", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = sueldo
                   comando.Parameters.Add("@acceso", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = acceso
                   comando.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = login
                   comando.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password
                   comando.Parameters.Add("@estado", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = estado
                   comando.Parameters.Add("@imagen", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = fichero
                   conexion.Open()
                   comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
                   ok = True
               End Using
           End Using
       Catch ex As Exception
       End Try

       Return ok
   End Function
   ```